# Как работает increase в Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

Для работы начал изучать мониторинг и метрики. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу никак понятно для себя найти объяснение того, как работает функция increase(). Перебрал много источников, но так и не смог понять, что это такое. Можете ли вы, простым языком и каким-нибудь примером, объяснить, что делает данная функция?

Comment: Чем официальная документация не угодила? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase

Comment: Тем, что я все равно еще не понял ничего, хотя очень стараюсь (и официальную документацию я прочитал первым делом).

Comment: А мы не поняли, что именно вы не поняли :)

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, что делает данная функция. не могу четко сформулировать.  Прошу помочь мне в этом

Comment: «что делает данная функция» — считает, на сколько увеличилась указанная метрика в течение указанного промежутка времени

Answer (score 1):

Функция `increase()` возвращает насколько счётчик (counter) увеличился за указанный промежуток.

В самом простом случае - это разница между текущим значением счётчика и значением в начале указанного промежутка. Если сброс счётчика присутствовал - функция вернёт насколько счётчик увеличился (увеличение от начал промежутка до сброса + увеличение с момента сброса)

Также под капотом `increase()` использует `rate()` и потом просто суммирует результаты за указанный промежуток. Поэтому результат может оказаться нецелочисленным, даже если значение счётчика всегда целочисленные.

Небольшой пример: выражения `increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"} [5m])` и `node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"} - node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"} offset 5m` возвращают похожие, но не идентичные результаты, даже в отсутствие сбросов. [Демо](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=increase(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%20%5B5m%5D)%20%0A*%20on()%20group_left(method)%20absent(nonexistent%7Bmethod%3D%22increase%22%7D)%20%23%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%20label%20method%20%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%0Aor%20node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%20-%20node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%20offset%205m&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h).

Answer (score 0):

функция increase() возвращает разницу между точками во временном ряду.
Из значения последней точки вычитается значение первой, результат возвращается.

Comment: Не совсем, также выполняется экстраполяция для подгонки под запрошенный временной промежуток

Comment: Ещё она учитывает ресеты (сбросить на ноль) счётчиков.